# ErrorException Array to string conversion in Controller file

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello guys please I'm having this laravel error in my controller and I need help

Here's my controller

```
        public function expectingpost(Request $request)
            {

                DB::table('expectings') ->insert([

                    $validatedData = $request->validate([
                        "time" => 'required|date_format:H:i',
                        "day" => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
                        "name" => 'required'
                    ]).

                    "time" => $request->time,
                    "day" => $request->date,
                   "name" => $request->name
                ]);

                return back() -> with('expecting', $request->input('name') . ' has been added as your guest');
            }
        }
```

PLease guys I seriously need fast responses because this has kept me on deck for long. Thank you

Comment: You're trying to concatenate arrays, that's not how it works. Please read [Writing The Validation Logic](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)

Comment: Why do you do a validation inside the insert?

Comment: Did my answer help your problem? :)

Comment: What is "this error"? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't validate your data inside your insert, this should be first validating your data, then use it to create your model. Another improvement use Eloquent models, there is no reason not to if you are just starting out.

```
public function expectingpost(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'time' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
        'day' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
        'name' => 'required'
    ]).

    Expecting::create($validatedData);

    return back()->with('expecting', $validatedData['name'] . ' has been added as your guest');
}
```

The Eloquent Model you need.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Expecting extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['time', 'day', 'name'];
}
```